# OCR Music Notes reader and player

Tags: gratis, ocr, music-recognition

I'm looking for `Windows` software that OCR music notes from pc. The input is paper with music notes. The software should enable to use the pc camera for snapshot and then plays the notes. Please mention gratis other than `Audiveris` and `SharpEye`.